# Python: Loading instance variables from another module class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Let's take 2 small classes

## ClassOne.py

```
class load_tuple:

 def __init__(self):
   self.envdata = ('server', '192.168.56.101')
```

## Classtwo.py

```
from ClassOne import load_tuple
class read_tuple:

 a = load_tuple()
 name = input("Enter tuple name")
```

And I will send input as "envdata" which is my instance tuple variable from ClassOne.py and this name stored at variable "name" at above class.

So what I am trying to achieve here is , how can I call env_data tuple by substituting its name via name variable ?

I tried with `a.name` but its giving me as

```
no such attributes such as name for a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ensure the input is valid, and that the instance contains a member with that name

```
a.__dict__[name]
```

Will access the value stored there.

That is,

```
a.__dict__["x"]
```

Is the same as

```
a.x
```

### Update:

The proper way to do this is

```
vars(a)[name]
```

Which is equivalent to `a.__dict__[name]`.

Comment: Yes I know that's​ but I want it to be accessed via input value. If name is envdata then I have to load it if its not then I shouldn't. But I may have many tuples so I am looking for something like a.name as name holds envdata and envdata is a tuple. Thia kind of loading I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Ten-Coin see if the new answer suits you, you need to ensure that "name" contains a valid string.

Comment: No.  My friend. I am sorry for not to be more clear . But regarding your answer That's the point. Always name value may not be envdata and always I may not have single tuple

Comment: Okay well, if the value exists, you can access it at a.__dict__[name]. This will only work if the value exists.